# How do I prove the adjoint matrix is the adjoint of the operator

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that $A^t$ is the adjoint of $A$ if we are in the euclidean spaces:

$\langle Au,v\rangle=(Au)^tv=u^tA^tv=\langle u,A^tv\rangle$

(where $\langle u,v\rangle=u^tv$)

I couldn't prove the complex case, where the inner product is defined as $\langle u,v\rangle=u^t\overline v$.

So we have to prove $\langle Au,v\rangle=\langle u,A^*v\rangle$, where $A^*$ is the adjoint matrix of $A$, i.e., $A^*=\big(\overline A\big)^t$.

I need help

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $A* = \overline{A^T}$, hence $A^T = \overline{A^*}$. So $\langle Au, v \rangle = (Au)^T\overline{v} = u^T(A^T\overline{v}) = u^T(\overline{A^*}\overline{v}) = u^T\overline{A^*v} = \langle u, A^*v \rangle$.

Comment: thank you very much, that's exactly I was looking for