# can I use the definition of adjoint matrix to find the adjoint of an operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, quantum-mechanics, complete-spaces

i have an operator and i need to find his adjoint, the operator is:  $$U_{m,n}=|O_m\rangle\langle O_n|$$
where i can say that
$$|O_m\rangle=A_{m,1}$$
and
$$\langle O_n|=B_{1,n}$$
so i can say that
$$
U_{m,n}=A_{m,1}.B_{1,n}
$$
$$ (U_{m,n})^*=(A_{m,1}.B_{1,n})^*$$
I know the properties for the adjunct, and so I can build on that, but I'm not sure if I can do this manipulation with the operator to find its adjunct

Comment: i´ve already found a answer in another question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758120/how-do-i-prove-the-adjoint-matrix-is-the-adjoint-of-the-operator

Comment: Delete the question, then!